# Delete method not working in MongoDB. Whenever I delete a voucher I get a CastError

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, postman, mongoose-schema

The message of the error: `"message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"{ [Function: ObjectID]\n`

I tried typecasting the id variable into an ObjectId.

VoucherController:

```
    module.exports.deleteVoucher = function(req, res, next) {

    var lectionId = req.params._id;
    var lectionId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
    if (!lectionId || lectionId === "") {
    return res.json({ "success": false, "msg": "You need to send the ID of 
    the Offer", "error": err });
    }

    Voucher.findByIdAndRemove(lectionId, function (err, removed) {
    if (err) {
      return res.json({ "success": false, "msg": "Error while deleting 
    Offer", "error": err });
    }

    res.status(200).json({ "success": true, "msg": "Offer deleted" });
    });

    };
```

How can I solve this objectId problem?

This is the model I used:

This is the route in the index.js:

```
router.delete('/voucher/delete/:_id', voucherCtrl.deleteVoucher);
```

When I add a typecast to an ObjectId I get Error 500,
Internal Server Error.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

cast string to mongoose Object id

```
module.exports.deleteVoucher = function(req, res, next) {

var lectionId = req.params._id;


if (!lectionId || lectionId === "") {
   return res.json({ "success": false, "msg": "You need to send the ID of the Offer", "error": err });
}

let lectionObjectId = mongoose.mongo.ObjectId(lectionId);
// or  lectionObjectId= mongoose.Types.ObjectId(lectionId)    

Voucher.remove({"_id":lectionObjectId}, function (err, removed) {
   if (err){
    return res.json({ "success": false, "msg": "Error while deleting Offer", "error": err });
   }

   res.status(200).json({ "success": true, "msg": "Offer deleted" });
});

};
```

Comment: When I do that I get error 500 internal server error. Is there any way I can avoid this error?

Comment: This is the error{
    "err": {},
    "msg": "500 Internal Server Error",
    "data": null
}

Comment: Yes here is the full code of the Voucher Controller: https://ideone.com/Bjn73n and this is the routing:                                                             router.get('/voucher/get', voucherCtrl.getVouchers);
router.post('/voucher/post', voucherCtrl.postVoucher);
router.delete('/voucher/delete/:_id', voucherCtrl.deleteVoucher);

Comment: in your remove function if error occured you print this `return res.json({ "success": false, "msg": "Error while deleting Offer", "error": err });`... and error you are getting is `{ "err": {}, "msg": "500 Internal Server Error", "data": null }` .... from where this error comes , you need to find out

Comment: the error you are getting is different than error print on failed to delete

Comment: make sure that your function is being called or not

Comment: make request to `module.exports.deleteVoucher = function(req, res, next) { return res.json('working');}`

Comment: I tried it now and it prints "working" which means the function is being called correctly.

Comment: now please findout , from where `{ "err": {}, "msg": "500 Internal Server Error", "data": null }` . --  this error being printed

Comment: please also check database , your record is being deleted or not ?

Comment: When I'm printing the id I am receiving from the parameters it shows me that it is empty, could this be the problem?

Comment: yes , if id is empty means your document is not being deleted

Comment: And no they are not deleted from the database

Comment: This is how I call the delete method in postman: http://localhost:3000/api/voucher/delete/:?_id=5d38f5582345016ca41b841c

Comment: mongoose.mongo.ObjectId(lectionId) is what causes Error 505, so I changed the method to this way: https://ideone.com/h0HC09 and this is the error I'm receiving now: { "message": "3 Voucher not found with id :" }

Comment: your url in post man should be : `http://localhost:3000/api/voucher/delete?_id=5d38f5582345016ca41b841c`